# Python: Element is not clickable selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to write a program in Python that click to the next page until the it reaches to the last page. I followed some old posts on Stackoverflow and wrote the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/yasirmuhammad/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags")



while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('next').click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

However, when I run the program, it throws following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags&amp;sort=votes&amp;page=3" rel="next" title="go to page 3">...</a> is not clickable at point (1180, 566). Other element would receive the click: <html class="">...</html>
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
```

I also followed a thread of Stackoverflow ([selenium exception: Element is not clickable at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132158/selenium-exception-element-is-not-clickable-at-point)) but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close this banner first -

[image]

Since selenium opens a fresh browser instance so the website will ask you to store cookies every time you run the script. It is this exact banner which is coming in the way of selenium clicking your "next" button. Use this code to delete that close button -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='grid--cell fc-white js-notice-close']").click()
```

Also,  `driver.find_element_by_link_text('next')` will throw a StaleElementReferenceException. Use this locator instead -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'next')]").click()
```

**Final code -**

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='grid--cell fc-white js-notice-close']").click()


while True:
  try:
      time.sleep(3)
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'next')]").click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still getting the following error:

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Thanks. Program works for couple of clicks but then it throws following error:

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: @user2293224 My bad, check the final code, you need to put the sleep inside the loop so that it waits for some time when the new page loads. Its working on my side.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question to click through the **next** page until the it reaches to the last page, you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
  from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='grid--cell fc-white js-notice-close' and @aria-label='notice-dismiss']"))).click()
  while True:
      try:
      driver.execute_script(("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"))
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pager fr']//a[last()]/span[@class='page-numbers next']")))
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pager fr']//a[last()]/span[@class='page-numbers next']").click()
      except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException) :
      print("Last page reached")
      break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Last page reached
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that need to be taken care of:

1. It seems the element is hidden by the cookies banner. By scrolling
   the page the element can be made available.
2. When you click on the
   `next` - the page is reloaded. So you need to handle the
   `StaleElementException`.

Adding both these the code looks as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags")
driver.execute_script(("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"))

while True:
    try:
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_link_text('next')).click().perform()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass

print "Reached the last page"
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error and the solution is not to scroll the window to the object(Maybe it can fix some errors but not in my case).
My solution is using javascript, the code as follows:

```
click_goal = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s_position_list"]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h3')
web.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click_goal)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem:After login the page i cant able to click any element.when i try to click on the element it shows the error shild crossed.

My solution is using javascript,the code as follows:
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li/a     self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).